# c# WPF TreeView in ListView via CellTemplate

Tags: c#, wpf, listview, treeview, celltemplate

I am new to WPF and XAML..

I want to add an TreeView into a ListView Element with a CellTemplate..

I want to bind each ListViewItem to a Custom class called "Symbol"

This Class has an Property called "Name" and a Property called "Images".

"Name" is just a String, which should be the root Element of the TreeView..

"Images" is a List of Strings.

Each entry of this list should be an Children of this TreeView..

And please do not just leave a code snippet, i want to understand how CellTemplates work!

Thank you!

```
<Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="listview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="326" Margin="0,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="499">
        <ListView.View>
            <GridView>
                <GridViewColumn Header="Symbols" Width="200"  >
                    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <StackPanel>
                                <TreeView>
                                <!--
                                    what to be done here?
                                -->
                                </TreeView>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                </GridViewColumn>
            </GridView>
        </ListView.View>
    </ListView>
    <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="250" Margin="504,33,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="250">
        <Border x:Name="image_preview" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Height="250" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="250"/>
    </Border>

</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should bind `ListView` to a collection of `Symbol` objects.
Now, every cell of your `ListView` is bound to `Symbol` object. If I understand you correctly, each `Symbol` should be a `TreeView` with root node header displaying `Name` property and collection of children displaying `Images` strings.

This can be achieved this way:

```
<TreeView >
    <TreeViewItem Header="{Binding Name}" ItemsSource="{Binding Images}" />    
</TreeView>
```

Comment: so "easy" .. :) thank you! but now there comes another "problem" .. when my mouse is over an treeview item, i cant scroll throw the listview with the mousewheel .. is there a possibility to avoid this and give the listview only listing to the mousewheel? i tried Focusable=false on the treeview, but same effect..

Comment: another question.. is there a possibility to have two different items, one for the root node and one for the childs? cause then i can style them different .. ?!

Comment: Of course, you need to set `TreeViewItem.ItemTemplate`. It will be used for child nodes.

Comment: yes, i have solved this alright.. but my biggest problem now is the mousewheel scroll behaviour.. i will try to catch mousewheel event and "scroll by hand" .. or did you have a better way?